# upsert into a table based on a value in JSON

Tags: javascript, postgresql, meteor, knex.js

I am using `passport-bnet` in order to authenticate users with battlenet (they can have multiple services). I have a user object that is formatted as follows:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Meow",
  "battlenet": {
    "id": 5,
    "tag": "obviously-not-a-real-battletag#1234"
  }
}
```

When I authenticate a user, I am given the id of the battlenet user in the response. What I am attempting to do is select the id from this json field and create it if it does not exist.

```
passport.use(new Battlenet({/**...*/}, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  database
    .select('*')
    .where('battlenet->id', '=', profile.id)
    .then(user => done(null, user))
    .catch(done);
});
```

However, I am having a bit of trouble. How can I upsert this user document to include some defaults? Essentially, I want something similar to this kind of modifier in mongo

```
{
  $setOnInsert: { name: profile.tag.replace(/\W/, '') },
  $set: { battlenet: profile }
}
```

How would this be done via knex and postgres?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit hard time to understand your schema and what you would like to happen when e.g. the same query is ran twice. Feel free to update question and I might be able to give more complete answer.

Generally for knex there has been discussion about upsert in

https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/54 and https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1121

Discussion was concluded that one should still use raw SQL (`knex.raw`) fr upsert.

For SQL parts of the question I believe that key is that you need to create  `UNIQUE` constraint for your `battlenet->id` attribute. After that it is possible to do `INSERT`s which conflicts on duplicate ids inside JSONB attribute.

Something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t_id ON t((json->>'id'));
```

After that it should be easy to write upsert which actually updates just some JSONB attributes with help of `jsonb_set` function.